# AWS Route53で 「.com」ドメインを取得しましたがgandi.netが表示されます

Tags: aws

AWS Route53で 「.com」ドメインを取得しましたが取得したドメインにアクセスしても「gandi.net」が表示されます。

その後、ワードプレスを再インストールしWP_HOMEなど設定しましたが変化はありませんでした。
nginxの設定も間違いありませんし、ネームサーバにも問題はありません。
これは一体なぜでしょうか？

表示されるのはこちらです。
https://www.gandi.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GandiというのはAmazonの上位レジストラ（ドメインの卸問屋のような物）のようです。  
ですから、Amazonで購入したばかりで何も設定をしていないと、ここのサイトのIPアドレスを指すようになっているのでしょう。

一般にドメイン名をWebサーバなどに結びつけるには、2つの事をする必要があります。どちらかを忘れているか、設定した直後のため世界中のDNSサーバまで浸透していないのだと思います。

1. DNSサーバの設定
   そのドメイン名でIPアドレスを引くのに使うDNSサーバを指定します。ドメインを購入したレジストラのWebインターフェイスを使えるはずです。
   Amazonで購入したドメインの場合、Route 53のサーバを使うようデフォルトで設定されているかも知れません。
2. IPアドレスの設定
   1で指定したDNSサーバの設定です。Route 53を使うなら、Webインターフェイスが用意されています。
   ドメイン名で問合せを受けた際に返すIPアドレスですので、WebサーバなどのIPアドレスを指定します。

Comment: TORブラウザで見るとテストページのHTMLが表示されました。
ChromeやIEでは現状変わりません。
ChromeやIEはリセットやアンインストール、クッキーなどの削除などいろいろ試しましたが、できませんでした。

Torだからといって、国ごとにアクセス制限をつけてはいません。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
色々調べるとDNS情報がブラウザ、クッキー、パソコン、ルーターに保存されるそうです。
最終的にルーターを再起動すると、Chromeでもドメインが正常に表示されました。